# How to find a character in a string using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, find, sql, string, characters

Using `Contains` to find a value using PowerShell is not working.

**Full Story:**

I have to get the `PartNo`, `Ver`, and `Rev` values from an SQL DB, and check if these values occur in the first line of the text file. I get the first line of the file and store it in `$EiaContent`. The `PartNo` is associated with `MAFN` as in `$partNo=Select PartNo Where MAFN=xxx`. Most of the time `MAFN` returns one `PartNo`. But in some cases for one `MAFN` there could be multiple `PartNo`. So the query returns multiple `PartNo(PartNo_1,PartNo_2,PartNo_3,and PartNo_4)` but only one of these will be in the text file.

**The issue is** that each of these `PartNo`. is treated as a single character in PowerShell. `$partNo.Length` is `4`. Therefore, my check `If ($EiaContent.Contains("*$partNo*"))` fails and it shouldn't in this case because I can see that one of the `PartNo` is mentioned in the file. Also, `Contains` wouldn't work if there was one `PartNo`. I use like as in `If ($EiaContent -like "*$partNo*")` to match the `PartNo` and it worked but it doesn't work when there are multiple `PartNo`.

**I have tried:**

`If ($partNo.Contains($EiaContent)){}` and `If ($partNo -like "*$EiaContent*"){}` but neither of these work either.

Data type of `$partNo` is a string and so is `$EiaContent`. The data type of `PartNo` in SQL is `varchar(50)` collation is `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, and I am using PowerShell Core 7.2 and SQL 2005

I have been stuck on this for a [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XwFj.png) couple of days now so any help is appreciated.

**Full Code:**

```
$EiaContent = (Get-Content $aidLibPathFolder\$folderName\$fileName  -TotalCount 1)
Write-host $EiaContent
#Sql query to get the Part Number 
$partNoQuery = "SELECT PartNo FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vMADL_EngParts] Where MAFN = $firstPartTrimmed"
$partNoSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $partNoQuery
#Eliminate trailing spaces
$partNo = $partNoSql.PartNo.Trim()
If ($EiaContent.Contains("*$partNo*")) {
   Write-Host "Part Matches"
}
Else {
   #Send an email stating the PartNo discrepancy 
}
```

### Example variable output values

- Variable `$partNo` equals `A1023 A1023MD C0400 C0400MD`
- Variable `$EiaContent` equals `O40033( C0400 REV N VER 004, 37 DIA 4.5 BRAKE DRUM OP3 )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned SQL query result is one long string with white space concatenating each value. Saving this result as a variable with PowerShell saves that long string as its value.

Use [`split()`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html) on the `$partNo` variable to transform the SQL result values into an [`array`](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html). Then use [`foreach-object`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html) against `$partNo` to iterate over each of its value to check if any of those are contained within  `$EiaContent` as you prefer.

> **For minimal changes** to your existing logic:
>
> ### New Logic Adjustment
>
> ```
> $partNo = $partNo.Split().Trim();
> $partNo | % {
>     If ( $EiaContent.Contains( $_ ) ) {
>        Write-Host "Part Matches"
>     }
>     Else {
>         Write-Host "Part Doesn't Match"
>        #Send an email stating the PartNo discrepancy 
>     }
> };
> ```

### Full Script Example

```
$EiaContent = (Get-Content $aidLibPathFolder\$folderName\$fileName  -TotalCount 1)
Write-host $EiaContent
#Sql query to get the Part Number 
$partNoQuery = "SELECT PartNo FROM [NML_Sidney].[dbo].[vMADL_EngParts] Where MAFN = $firstPartTrimmed"
$partNoSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $partNoQuery
#Eliminate trailing spaces    
$partNo = $partNo.Split().Trim();
$partNo | % {
        If ( $EiaContent.Contains( $_ ) ) {
           Write-Host "Part Matches"
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "Part Doesn't Match"
           #Send an email stating the PartNo discrepancy 
        }
    };
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)

  > **Key**
  >
  > `strSeparator`  The character used to split up each string, by
  > ***default whitespace (space/newline/tab)***
- [Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [If](https://ss64.com/ps/if.html)